# Unable to mass edit leads

Tags: leads, lead-conversion

I am new to sfdc.I had created a sales process in my organisation.For creating leads we have two options available.In my organisation research team is there to assign leads to users.Before creating records they had access to mass edit to all leads.But,after creating record type.They can't do mass edit I don't know why they have to go to each and every lead to edit.Before they have option to edit title and company.But it's not possible right now.. for reference [image]

Please help me    thanks in advance

Pavan kumar o.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution for this problem.i am assigning the old leads to a new record type with WORKBENCH based on the record type Id.from now onwards in my organisation have two process and for mass editing i had created view based on record types..

Answer (score 3):

What about Record Types ? Do you have them on the Lead object ?

If so you need to ensure that the results(aka the records displayed) all belong to the same Record Type. You might need to include a Filter for that on the View.

Take a look at this article - Unable to Inline Edit in a List View (https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000003911)

Source : [Link](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000p1k7AAA)

Comment: Ya thanks i know it.We can create new views Based on record type.But the client requirement is want to edit based on company.While try  to do that they didn't get edit option.is there any to do that. once again thank's             Thanks in advance @Prabhat Kumar

Answer (score 2):

@user2185482, from the documentation Prabhat provided, you can see that inline editing like you want is only possible if all records are of the same Record Type.

As you said, you'd like to filter lead list views based on the company, not on the record type. However, if such a filter shows leads with different record types, you won't be able to do inline editing, and will have to edit from within each lead.

The solution (assuming no custom coding) might be to have all your leads stay as a single record type until your organization's Research Team goes through and assigns them to your users. Then have workflow rules that update the newly assigned leads' record type as appropriate.

EG:

1. All leads prior to review by Research Team are set to one record type, maybe call it 'Pre-Assignment', or 'Waiting on Research Team'. You get the idea.
2. Create a workflow rule for each Record Type you plan on updating leads to after being assigned.
3. Logic for each workflow rule could be something like "If lead has been modified by Research Team and has been assigned to a user, AND lead meets the criteria demonstrating that it belongs to Record Type Y, then update to Record type Y"

Comment: I had tried to assign old leads to my new record type through dataloader it works in developer org.But it is not working in EE can you help me@smohyee

Comment: @user2185482 You probably need to ensure that your user profile has necessary permissions to a) Use data loader in your org, b) Access that new record type for leads, and c) Edit leads